# Validation range rule doesn't occur dynamically in textbox field from automated calculation

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, textbox

I want a range rule validation to occur, when a calculated value is pushed to a textbox field, but the validation only displays when user enters values directly into the textbox. The validation doesn't occur from the calculation of values, which the user puts into other textboxes. How can I make the validation occur dynamically from automated calculation?
I'm rather new to C# and mvvm, so maybe I haven't got it right. I don't understand so much of IDataErrorInfo, so I would rather use INotifyPropertyChanged if possible.

```
    private int _FIMSamlet_score;
    public int FIMSamlet_score
    {
        get { return this._FIMSamlet_score; }
        set
        {
            if (Int32.Parse(value.ToString()) < 18 || Int32.Parse(value.ToString()) > 126)
            { throw new ArgumentException("The value must be between 18 and 126"); }
            this._FIMSamlet_score = value;
            CalculateFimSamletscore();
            this.OnPropertyChanged("FIMSamlet_score");
        }
    }
```

**My method for calculation on entered values.**

```
   private void CalculateFimSamletscore()
    {
        try
        {
            FIMSamlet_score = Convert.ToInt32(a)
                + Convert.ToInt32(b)
                + Convert.ToInt32(c)
                + Convert.ToInt32(d)
                + Convert.ToInt32(e)
                + Convert.ToInt32(f)
                + Convert.ToInt32(g)
                + Convert.ToInt32(h)
                + Convert.ToInt32(i)
                + Convert.ToInt32(j)
                + Convert.ToInt32(k)
                + Convert.ToInt32(l)
                + Convert.ToInt32(m);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<TextBox Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Name="fIM_samletScore" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150" Background="WhiteSmoke">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="FIMSamlet_score" Mode="TwoWay" ValidatesOnExceptions="true" NotifyOnValidationError="true" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ExceptionValidationRule/>
                <validators:FIMRangeRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

**I have also made a validation class**

```
public class FIMRangeRule : ValidationRule
{

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Feltet må ikke være tomt. Indtast gyldig værdi.");
        else
        {

            if ((Int32.Parse(value.ToString()) < 18) || (Int32.Parse(value.ToString()) > 126))
                return new ValidationResult
                (false, "Værdi udenfor gyldig interval 18-126");
        }
        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: `CalculateFimSamletscore();` is called from `FIMSamlet_score`'s setter, which again sets `FIMSamlet_score`, isn't it causing a Stackoverflow?

Comment: @JohnSaunders. Ok, thanks. I didn't knew that.

Comment: @kennyzx. Yes you are right. But how do I call the method 'CalculateFimSamletScore();' and at the same time set the property?

Comment: when any of the values of `a,b,c..,m` is changed, called `CalculateFimSamletScore()`, that is, treat `a` like   `_FIMSamlet_score`, make it a property, and called `CalculateFimSamletScore()` in `a`'s setter.

Comment: @kennyzx. Thanks, that helped me a lot with the stackoverflowing. But I still don't get a validation range rule from the calculated result.The validation only occurs when user enter values directly into the textbox. Maybe it isn't possible with a textbox? I'm also not sure if I should put the validation in a class or if I can just have it in the property getter.

Comment: @userJJL I have found the cause of `failing to display validation result by updating source`, but I don't know if there is a good trick to do with this (there should be an easy way), so I suggest you ask a new question, providing less code to demonstrate the problem, just set the `FIMSamlet_score` Property in one line, so people will not be scared by the number of lines of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [WPFTutorial.net](http://wpftutorial.net/ValidationErrorByCode.html).

> A ValidatioRule in a BindingExpression only triggers, when the target side of the binding changes.

In your code, the TextBox is the target side. That is why you can't see the validation result.

The tutorial continues with a tip to set the validation error by code.

Comment: Thx, I'll try his code snippet. But since I'm new to this I'm not sure if I should create a new eventhandler like textchanged and put the validationerror there. If I put it in the validator, it doesn't seem to recognize the textbox. Well, I'll just try a few things and see how it works.